# Skip first occurrence of semicolon using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to skip the first semicolon in the string  and do a split on the rest of the semicolon using a regular expression:

```
lines = </li> <li> Urinary tract infection </li> <li> Respiratory infection </li> <li> Sinus problems; and </li> <li> Ear infections; <li> Some more info </li>
```

I am using this code to split this at every semicolon except the first one:

```
lines.split(/(?<!\\\\);/)
```

My expected output is:

```
["</li> <li> Urinary tract infection </li> <li> Respiratory infection </li> <li> Sinus problems; and </li> <li> Ear infections","<li> Some more info </li>" ]
```

Note that the string could be long with any number of semicolons but I want to prevent the splitting from happening only from the first semicolon.

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/D4Chmm) - here, it is split at the last semi-colon, however.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the quick response .The string I posted is just an example . The original string that im working is too long and has multiple semicolons . So i want only the first semi colon skipped and rest all semi colons considered.I just updated the question

Comment: What about [this demo](http://ideone.com/I7rB7B)? `lines.scan(/\A[^;]*;[^;]*|[^;]+/)`?

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem. What is the goal of the split? Why aren't you using a parser, like Nokogiri, since you're trying to manipulate HTML. Regular expressions fall apart quickly when dealing with XML/HTML text.

Answer (score 0):

Must I use a regex?

```
str = "Now is; the time; for all good; people; to party" 

f, sc, l = str.partition(';')
af, *a = str[str.index(';')+1..-1].split(';')
[f+sc+af, *a]
  #=> ["Now is; the time", " for all good", " people", " to party"]
```

The steps:

```
f, sc, l = str.partition(';')
   #=> ["Now is", ";", " the time; for all good; people; to party"] 
f  #=> "Now is" 
sc #=> ";" 
l  #=> " the time; for all good; people; to party" 
idx = str.index(';')+1
   #=> 7 
b = str[idx..-1]
   #=> " the time; for all good; people; to party" 
af, *a = b.split(';')
af #=> " the time" 
a  #=> [" for all good", " people", " to party"] 
[f+sc+af, *a]
   #=> ["Now is; the time", " for all good", " people", " to party"]
```

For the OP's example:

```
f, sc, l = lines.partition(';')
af, *a = lines[lines.index(';')+1..-1].split(';')
[f+sc+af, *a]
  #=> ["</li> <li> Urinary tract infection </li> <li> Respiratory infection\    
         </li> <li> Sinus problems; and </li> <li> Ear infections",
  #    " <li> Some more info </li>"]
```

Another way:

```
b = str.sub(';', 0.chr).split(';')
  #=> ["Now is\u0000 the time", " for all good", " people", " to party"] 
a[0].sub!(0.chr, ';')
  #=> "Now is; the time" 
a #=> ["Now is; the time", " for all good", " people", " to party"]
```

Comment: Does it mean you assume there will be some specific number of elements in the result?

Comment: @Wikor, my understanding (which I believe is consistent with the desired result from the OP's  example) is that the string is to be split on semi-colons, except the first semi-colon is skipped, making it a character of the first element (string) of the array returned. No?

Comment: Well, I am just against code only answers. Some comments on the code would be of great help.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The reason I use regex is because of the HTML involved. I makes my life much easier when dealing with spaces and special characters. I came up with a similar code but it doesn't seem to fit in the system im working on . so i specially need to get this done using regex. I hope you are understanding my point here.

Comment: @Wiktor, I generally provide explanations (sometimes going overboard), but here I thought showing what is returned by each statement is sufficient. I'll add a bit, however.

Comment: Raghu, I don't understand why the fact that the strings are HTML is relevant. A character is a character. Can you provide a counter-example to what I suggested? As @theTinMan noted, using a regex with HTML is fraught with peril.